# Is anything wrong with my query

Tags: sql

I have a simple query:

```
SELECT stco, sum(STSD) As "Shipped Dollars"
FROM MSTDW
```

This says there is something wrong with the select column stco.

However, both fields exist and this:

```
SELECT stco
FROM MSTDW
```

works and this

```
SELECT sum(STSD) As "Shipped Dollars"
FROM MSTDW
```

Works too.

What could be wrong with having both?

Thanks

Comment: Are you missing a GROUP BY statement?

Comment: To be more helpful, please include the exact error messages that you recieve.  `This says there is something wrong with the select column stco.` prevents us from knowing everything that you are being told.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this, a group by, to get the sum of each `stco`

```
SELECT stco, sum(STSD) As "Shipped Dollars"
FROM MSTDW 
group by stco
```

For apply aggregate functions you need to group; anyway, if you just want the sum of ALL column (I don't think you want that, but I add it just in case) do

```
SELECT stco, (select sum(STSD) from MSTDW) As "Shipped Dollars"
    FROM MSTDW 
    group by stco
```

This will list each `stco`, and repeat the `sum` of all column

Comment: The sum() function requires that all non-summed columns (stco) need to be grouped so the database can logically combine data.  Functions like these are called aggregates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function).

Answer (score 2):

In order to use an aggregate function (e.g. `SUM`) you need to define the grouping condition:

```
SELECT stco, sum(STSD) As "Shipped Dollars"
FROM MSTDW 
GROUP BY stco
```

The reason your second query works without `stco` is because the group is implicit (i.e. unconditional sum) in the single `SUM` value you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `stco` is not [aggregated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx), so you must add in into `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT stco, SUM(STSD) AS "Shipped Dollars"
FROM MSTDW 
GROUP BY stco
```

However you also can apply aggregate to `stco` too, like this:

```
SELECT AVG(stco) AS SomeValue, SUM(STSD) AS "Shipped Dollars"
FROM MSTDW
```

In general all values must be either aggregated or be in grouping keys section, which will separate aggregating regions of data.