# SQL sum all rows by id

Tags: sql

I am trying to learn SQL queries and have this scenario where I have this table:

Table1

```
       ID | Name | Hour
       ----------------
        1 | Mark | 2
        2 | ken  | 1.5
        3 | jake | 3
        1 | Mark | 1.8
        2 | ken  | 1
```

Expected result

```
       ID | Name | Hour
       ----------------
        1 | Mark | 3.8
        2 | ken  | 2.5
        3 | jake | 3
```

I have tried to use the `sum()` function but I get an error.

My query:

```
Select ID, Name, Sum(Hour) 
From Table1 
Where ID = ID
```

Response:

> 1. Kindly use Group by clause whenever the Aggregate functions (min(),max(),sum(),count(),...etc.,) and columns are used together.
> 2. Non aggregated columns present in SELECT columns should be used in GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is anything wrong with my query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936921/is-anything-wrong-with-my-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using aggregate function you need to use `Group By` like this:

```sql
 Select ID, Name , Sum(Hour) AS Hour From Table1
 Group By ID, Name
 Order By ID
```